# Arduino and PHP

Tags: php, arduino

I'm using an Arduino Uno to insert data via PHP and send SMS API. A value like 1234 is nicely inserted in the database but the API is not working, and the SMS not sent. What is the problem in my PHP code? Please help. Sorry for my English.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <Client.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
byte subnet[] = {255, 255, 255, 0};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 103);
char server[] = "www.wscedu.com";
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    delay(1000);
  } else if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 1) {
    Serial.print("IP Address:");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (client.connect(server, 80) > 0) {
    client.print("GET /tag.php?");
    client.print("value=1234"); // This
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.wscedu.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println(); // Empty line
    client.println(); // Empty line
    client.stop();
  }
  delay(10000);
}
```

Here is my PHP code: tag.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password","db");
$tag=$_GET["value"];
  $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tag_tbl (tag_value, status) VALUES ('".$tag."', 1)");
if ($result === false) {
  echo "SQL error:".$mysqli->error;
} else {
  header("location: https://vas.banglalinkgsm.com/sendSMS/sendSMS?msisdn='$phone_no'&message=tag Value: '".$tag."'&userID=userid123&passwd=wsr123&sender=WSC");
}
?>
```

Comment: If the header("location:...") get trigger, then there is nothing wrong with your code, you should check the API and the permission for the sms gateway. I tried `curl www.www.wscedu.com/tag.php?value=1234` (which is what your Arduino do, I got a error message "Duplicate entry", but if I change `value=1238`, it seems get redirect to the sms gateway but got a message "Success Count : 0 and Fail Count : 1", this seems to suggest that the issue is with the sms gateway.

Comment: assign your url string to a variable like `$url = "https://vas.banglalinkgsm.com/sendSMS/sendSMS?msisdn='$phone_no'&message=tag Value: '".$tag."'&userID=userid123&passwd=wsr123&sender=WSC"` and print it out to see anything correct? Also I think you need urlencode($url) the string before send it over.